# Animate UIView grow from left rather than center

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

The UIView `button` has a width of 44 and it should animate expanding to 90. Currently when the animation starts it realigns the view to the center at 44 width before expanding both the left and right sides to 90.

```
self.button.widthConstraint?.isActive = false
self.button.width(90)
UIView.animate(
  withDuration: animationDuration,
  animations: {
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
)
```

How do I animate the expansion from the right side only? I want the left to be pinned while the right side increases it's x position.

Answer (score 2):

Setup your constraints such that the leading, trailing, top, and bottom anchors are pinned, and then animate a change in the trailing constraint.

Comment: How do you pin anchors? Is this with a `cgaffinetransform`